# Does SGX or Gramine support mmap files?

Tags: apache-storm, sgx

I use Storm In my application in order to to store and retrieve adapter information , Storm uses boltdb, which is a key-value store based on mmap, to manage the data.
I have created docker image using gsc and started the container inside the sgx.
when I want to add a datasource I get error Error="function not implemented" , while app is working without sgx perefctly.
the error occurs in line:
catalog, err := storm.Open(absCatalogPath)
Is sgx or gramine support mmap files like storm? how could I solve the problem?